# Как сделать эти 3 блока на WP, в цикле кастомными записями или кастомными полями?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap

Верстка сделана так что 2 первых блока отдельно а третий отдельно. Как я понимаю делать это записями в цикле нет смысла? Не думаю что будет добавляться 4 блок(логики нет). Т.е. можно просто создать на странице кастомные поля и сделать их для всех 3 блоков. Только было бы неплохо разделить кастомные поля чем то визуально. Посоветуете как лучше сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <section id="modals">
      <div class="line clearfix">
          <img src="img/catalog.png" alt="">
          <div class="col-md-4 ">
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="section-head">
                      Условия доставки
                  </div>
                  <p>Доставка букетов с онлайн-бутика по Киеву и Харькову осуществляется
                      бесплатно. Скорость выполнения доставки - дотрех часов с момента оплаты.
                      Мы принимаем заказы
                      ежедневно с 9:00 до 20:00.</p>
                  <a class="more" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delivery-modal">подробнее</a>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="section-head">
                      Наш бутик
                  </div>
                  <p>Есть на карте места с повышенной концентрацией цветов, красоты, уюта и искусства. Приглашаем вас погрузиться в прекрасный мир бутика Magic Flower Lab.</p>
                  <a class="more" id="to-map" data-toggle="collapse" href="#map" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">показать на карте</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="line clearfix last">
          <img src="img/contact.png" alt="">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="section-head">
                      Напишите или позвоните нам
                  </div>
                  <p>Ежедневно с 09.00 до 20.00</p>
                  <p><a href="tel:+380675064101">+38 (067) 506 41 01</a></p>
                  <p> <a href="tel:+380442324757">+38 (044) 232 47 57</a></p>

                  <p><a href="mailto:zakaz@magicflowerlab.ua">zakaz@magicflowerlab.ua</a></p>
                  <a class="more" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-modal">отправить заявку</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: В причём верстка к "записями в цикле"? В чём собсно вопрос? И метка php тут каким боком?  Лишняя она. Да и bootstrap наверняка тоже. А если вопрос по вёрске, что и ВП не причём :)

Answer (score 0):

Выдвиньте вниз средний блок с помощью css. И весь цикл php останется на месте.

Что в цикле - кастомные записи или поля - значения не имеет.